Do we need a rail on both sides of stairs
We are renovating a room.  Currently, the stairs have railing at both side of the bottom of the stairs.  We would like to remove one side of railing, but we do not know if this is code compliant.
In the first picture you see how the stairs are now open at the bottom on the near side.  There used to be a short piece of railing (similar to what is on the far side) that went from the wall to the bottom of the stairs (we already took down the railing on the near side).  The other side still has railing to prevent people from falling into the basement (this will stay).
The second picture show the stairs from the opposite side.  Here, you see railing along the wall.  This railing will remain in place.
Is what is shown in the pictures code compliant?



Your local building department/inspector will have the last say, but I think the two last/bottom steps might not need it(but i think a pole at the bottom to swing on is a good idea also).

At which point one might as well add the handrail there, if only to support the pole better.

What you have is awkward (because you have to switch sides) but I believe generally meets code.  It'd be better if you had a single rail down the right (descending) side.  If you're concerned about the bottom step, you could simply extend it to the side and wrap around.

None of the railings shown in your photos are code-compliant where I live (Seattle), due to the shape of the handrail, the lack of returns to the wall at the rail ends, and the large open areas below the handrails. You are well advised to consult your local code authority as to permitted handrail designs.

I'm pretty sure the "open areas below the handrails" is a rule that has changed substantially over the years - which likely means an existing handrail is OK but on replacement it needs to be compliant with current rules.
